# Are there react native libraries to implement node-based UIs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've implemented a node-based UI within a react web app using react flow (https://reactflow.dev/). Currently I'm looking for something similar for the react native mobile version of my web app. Unfortunately react flow isn't supported for react native and I can't find any real alternatives.

I'm looking for suggestions for any kind of mind-map/network visualization library that I can use with react native.

Thanks a lot
Jakob

I've tried to use d3 for react native but it requires a ton of customization to get results like react flow in my web app when visualizing networks and nodes.